# type casting when return from function with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, casting, shared-ptr

```
std::shared_ptr<AbstractPrinter> parse_input_fiz(char const *input) {
    std::shared_ptr<FizPrinter> printer(FizPrinter);

    return printer;
}
```

FizPrinter inherited from AbstractPrinter. And i got next error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type could not convert ‘printer’
>   from ‘std::shared_ptr (*)(FizPrinter)’ to
>   ‘std::shared_ptr’    parser.cc   /pdf-i/src  line 63 C/C++
>   Problem

---

this function one of used in Factory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean

```
std::shared_ptr<FizPrinter> printer(new FizPrinter());
```

Your current code declares a function and the constructor for a `shared_ptr` takes a pointer.

Comment: Or better still, `return std::make_shared<FizPrinter>();`

Answer (score 2):

```
std::shared_ptr<FizPrinter> printer(FizPrinter);
```

means "printer is a function with argument FizPrinter".

See question 10.21: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html